# JavaScript/jQuery: rotate element on key press (tetris effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to rotate an element by pressing space bar, like a tetris effect. But so far I can only rotate it once, and the position()method doesn't seem to work like it does when using keys to move sideways. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    var div = $("#div");
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyCode === 37) div.css("left", (div.position().left - 1) + "px");
    if (keyCode === 39) div.css("left", (div.position().left + 1) + "px");
    if (keyCode === 32) div.css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png that way the rest of the community can benefit from it, Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rotate property is always `-90px`. I would have a variable that keeps track of the 'rotation' starting at 0. Then subtracting -90 on every space press. Keep in mind not go over 360, instead reset back to 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rotation = 0;
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    var div = $("#div");
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyCode === 37) div.css("left", (div.position().left - 1) + "px");
    if (keyCode === 39) div.css("left", (div.position().left + 1) + "px");
    if (keyCode === 32) {
      rotation -= 90;
      if (rotation < -360)
        rotation = 0;
      
      div.css('transform','rotate('+rotation+'deg)');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#div { 
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">test</div>
```